# Use EDMX file to generate a database?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have lost my SQL script to generate tables for my database, good thing its not for a client. I thought I had a backup but I do not. 
I do have an EDMX file in my project though, so is there any way that I can create the database schema off of the EDMX?

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking the designer surface? I remember it to have a "generate database" option.https://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/entity-framework-4-0-generating-sql-script-from-model

Comment: @jessehouwing, I didn't even notice that. Good call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click the EMDX design surface, you will find a generate database option there to give you your sql scripts or directly populate a database.